# angularjs e2e testing with partials

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e, angular-template

i have a url localhost:3000/apps which is made up of 2 partials, listApps, and createApps. Below is my app.html code which injects those 2 partials. I wish to know how to can switch from one partial to another and test each partial. My main issue is how can i set tab to active and test that partial or what do you guys think is best to test this. thanks

```
    <div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

<div class="container main-content" ng-controller="AppsCtrl">

  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{ alert.type }}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{ alert.msg }}</alert>
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/apps" class="active">My Applications</a></li>
  </ol>

  <tabset type="pills">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled" ng-hide="tab.hidden">
      <div ng-if="(tab.id == 'createApp')"><ng-include src="'app/apps/partials/create_app.html'"></ng-include></div>
      <div ng-if="(tab.id == 'listApp')"><ng-include src="'app/apps/partials/list_app.html'"></ng-include></div>
    </tab>
  </tabset>

</div>

<div ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></div>
```